# How can I make a persistent ssh tunnel?

Tags: macos, ssh, automation

I have a Mac laptop and would like to have a persistent ssh tunnel so I can always log in from outside the local network. I'm looking for something that will work when the server can't be reached initially (e.g. if I don't have an Internet connection when I boot it), and will automatically start the tunnel when possible.

I've tried putting an `@reboot autossh` line in my crontab, but I've found that sessions started with `autossh` disconnect every so often, and `autossh` quits if the first attempt fails. My current workaround is a small script and a cronjob:

```
# crontab
/home/blackl/bin/script &!

# script
#!/bin/sh
while true; do ssh -Ngn -R $some_port:localhost:22 $server; sleep 30; done;
```

Is there a better way to do this, or will I just have to be happy with this for now?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry this is a very late response, and you may have come across this solution already, but [here](http://www.zenspider.com/ruby/2011/11/ssh-tunneling-via-osx-s-launchctl.html) is how it can be done using OS X's launchctl mechanism.

I don't think he's got it *quite* right; you would use the "KeepAlive" key (with a value of "true") instead of the deprecated "OnDemand/false" key/value pair. Also, I don't know why he's forwarding to the identical port on the remote host (1666) as vs 22. Still - you get the idea. I've got mine up & running ok to our web server. *Much* more elegant than an infinite loop.

Oh, and instead of [Lingon](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) that he mentions, you can use the marvelous [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) to set it up, modify and monitor it. If you're not familiar with launchctl, I strongly suggest reading the primer in the program or the site to understand what's going on. Sorry - I would have linked to the primer, but I haven't built up enough of a rep :/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please paraphrase the contents of the link in case the link disappears in the future.

Comment: Ok - to paraphrase, you have to set up a launchd.plist file which implements a command of the form:

`/usr/bin/ssh -CN -c blowfish -o 5 -L 1666:localhost:1666 <server>` 

where <server> is defined in ~/.ssh/config. Use the KeepAlive/true key/value pair. Here, you're forwarding localhost:1666 to the remote <server>. man launchd.plist for how to do this - I haven't got enough characters left. :)

Comment: Thanks especially for the pointer to LaunchControl; it's a really slick tool.

Comment: Why not put it in the answer instead of comments!